# Use graphics 2D/3D animation tools in facebooks ads API

Tags: php, facebook, symfony

Hi anyone can suggest that isit possible to create graphic 2D/3D animation tools in add creatives using facebook ads API under specific campaign.

For example - Slideshow is there

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdVideo;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdVideoFields;

$video = new AdVideo(null, 'act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>');
$video->{AdVideoFields::SLIDESHOW_SPEC} = array (
  'images_urls' => array(
    '<IMAGE_URL_1>',
    '<IMAGE_URL_2>',
    '<IMAGE_URL_3>',
  ),
  'duration_ms' => 2000,
  'transition_ms' => 200,
);

$video->create();
```

Likewise is it possible to give for 2D/3D animation???